# What disk image should I choose for my Google Cloud VM so that pandas will work just as it does on my Mac?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, text-analysis

I followed a [handy tutorial](https://jeffdelaney.me/blog/running-jupyter-notebook-google-cloud-platform/) to setup a Google Compute Engine VM instance with data science libraries and Debian GNU/Linux 9 disk image. I ran a data exploration notebook I had put together on my local machine, and found `pandas.read_csv()` to screw up the import of my training data.

Correctly imported, the dataset is a pandas dataframe with one column ('text'). Each of 3000 entries in that column is an article from a biomedical literature corpus. What happens on the VM though is that some length threshold is applied and pandas shunts part of a given article to a new row of the dataframe. It does this to most but not all of the articles and the dataframe ends up with close to 6000 entries. More importantly, it's useless to try to train a model on.

I cloned my local environment using Vagrant but it looks like it might be difficult to get my disk image into Google Cloud and optimized. So, I thought I would check here first if anyone knows a simpler solution, like perhaps choosing a different machine type than Debian/Linux to set up my Compute Engine instance so that pandas functions work properly. Thanks for your input!

Comment: My guess is that maybe you have different locales or different Pandas versions between your local environment and the virtual machine. Can you double check the Pandas package version and can you [play](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with the `warn_bad_lines` and `quoting` options?

Answer (score 0):

After you login to the Google Cloud VM instance that has Debian/GNU Linux default, you can use the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

Else, if you prefer to use the pip installer, that works too:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then you can install other PyPi libraries, such as pandas as `sudo pip install pandas`
Remember that if you want to install libraries for Python 3.x, use `python3` instead of `python` in the above snippets.

Comment: Thanks. If you read my question, installing packages is not the problem. It's getting pd.read_csv () to work correctly.